# Simple question about independence and complex exponential function

Tags: probability, independence, characteristic-functions

Let $X,Y$ be Independent random variables. Why does their Independence implie the Independence of $e^{iuX}$ and $e^{iuY}$? $u$ is real in this case.

Comment: It wouldn't, but I still would like to understand and prove it. I mean is it generaly true that if $X,Y$ are independent than also $f(X),f(Y)$ are for some kind of f?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ which is defined by $f(x)=e^{iux}$ is Borel measurable. Hence if $B_1,B_2\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ are Borel sets then $f^{-1}(B_1),f^{-1}(B_2)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ are Borel, and we have:

$P(f(X)\in B_1,f(Y)\in B_2)=P(X\in f^{-1}(B_1),Y\in f^{-1}(B_2))=$
$=P(X\in f^{-1}(B_1))P(Y\in f^{-1}(B_2))=P(f(X)\in B_1)P(f(Y)\in B_2)$

We used the independence of $X$ and $Y$ here.